# Ethernet frequently disconnects in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have recently performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad X201. I have encountered a strange problem : Wifi works fine. Mobile internet tethering through USB works fine. However, when I connect through ethernet cable, internet connects initially. I can browse website. However, after 10sec-1min, the network shows connected but cannot browse websites. If I re-plug the ethernet cable, it again works for 10sec. If I switch off and on the ethernet connection from settings, again it works well for 10s-1min and again the same thing.

**/etc/resolve.conf**

```
  GNU nano 4.8                    /etc/resolv.conf                              
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

**01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```
GNU nano 4.8              01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 06
       serial: f0:de:f1:3f:55:d8
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.12-1 ip=172.16.11.245 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:31 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f2525000-f2525fff ioport:1820(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 5c:ac:4c:bd:f2:3f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192se driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f2400000-f2403fff
```

** Please find output of `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`  [here](https://gist.github.com/dub2s/785be0537d34a66c20bbe9a622584f1a#file-gistfile1-txt)

** ping 9.9.9.9**.

```
PING 9.9.9.9 (9.9.9.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C 
--- 9.9.9.9 ping statistics ---
42 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 41962ms
```

** uname -a**

```
Linux abhishek 5.8.0-63-generic #71~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 17:46:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/device/power/control**

```
on
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator I am not able to see anything special. '<info>  [1627230950.8105] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL' This is what I see between switching ON/OFF ethernet connection from settings. When the internet goes off after 10-15sec, it does not show anything specific.

Comment: @abhishek-dubey when you cannot browse websites after around 10 sec, does `ping` still work or no? From the `terminal` you can try `ping 9.9.9.9`. Please edit your question, and add result of ping. Thanks.

Comment: @abhishek-dubey Please run `uname -a` and post the output. Thanks.

Comment: @abhishek-dubey Also post output of `cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/device/power/control`

Comment: @Jags I have updated both of them. Seems like power control for ethernet is on.